# How to disable break mode

Tags: vb.net, break

My application works as it should and even when published still works perfectly its only when I close the application and it disappear that for some strange reason I get a message informing me that the application is in break mode, I would of thought if there was an error that it would appear when the application is loaded or an event, not when the application is closed completed and the user is finished with it. Because of this I was wondering is there anyway of removing this break mode error?

The error seems to be related to an un-handled event within System.Reactive.Core.dll

---

I have narrowed down the initial error to a multi-thread issue

```
Private _subscription As IDisposable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Checkthread = New Thread(AddressOf Me.CheckConnection)
    Checkthread.Start()

    _subscription =
                Observable _
               .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)) _
               .StartWith(-1) _
               .Select(Function(x) internetConnection()) _
               .ObserveOn(Me) _
               .Subscribe(Sub(x)
                              If x Then
                                  PicInternet.Hide()
                              Else
                                  PicInternet.Show()
                              End If
                          End Sub)



End Sub


Private Sub CheckConnection()
    If internetConnection() = False Then
        InternetStatus = False

    Else
        InternetStatus = True

    End If


End Sub
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong to cause a break mode error, between my initial Form1 loading and CheckConnection.

Comment: Please give us the complete, exact error message

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Reactive.Core.dll, I also received this after copying to the clipboard Additional information : Invoke Or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something to/with forms or controls after they have been disposed.  Thats the real problem you should focus on.

Comment: I have just edited my above question to hopefully narrow down the problem.

Comment: You need to stop your thread when the form is closing

Comment: Thank you, I missed such a obvious mistake.